# How to make a command string executing bash ("bash -c") to read the .bashrc

Tags: cygwin, bash, dotfiles

When I call a `bash` shell from another program to execute an command string I call

```
bash -c <shell commands>
```

This works pretty well, but the shell which gets invoked does not read the startup file `.bashrc`. I need this for environment variables and aliases set in the start-up file.
I tried

```
bash -i -c <shell commands>
```

and

```
bash -l -c <shell commands>
```

to read `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` but didn't have any luck. How can I enforce reading of a start-up file?

Note: I tried this only on Cygwin bash 4.1.0, but I assume this is a machine-independent issue.

Comment: I tried `bash -i -c <command>` in Linux and it does read the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: I tried `bash -i -c <command>` in Cygwin bash 3.1 and it does read the `.bashrc` file, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mentioned,

```
bash -i -c
```

*does* indeed source the start-up file.

I did something wrong in Emacs, my calling app; that's why it didn't work for me.

Apologies for the unnecessary question.